# IE always centers text in TD

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table, alignment

In IE 9, if I have the following HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <i>DO, Medical Epidemiologist</i>
    </td>
</tr>
```

it always centers the text. In Chrome and Firefox it aligns to the left.
How do I get IE to behave the same?

Comment: Add some CSS like `text-align: left`?

Comment: Not reproducible. The phenomenon is caused by something outside the code snippet posted. You should post a minimal sample document that actually causes the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not specifying an alignment, so the browser can use any default that it wants.

This is usually inherited from a parent element, but the exact inheritance rules aren't always consistant, especially with older browsers.

To fix this in pure HTML, add an `align` attribute like this:

```
<tr><td align="left"><i>DO, Medical Epidemiologist</i></td></tr>
```

A better fix is to use CSS though, like this:

```
td {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: No, browsers do not use any defaults they want. (Theoretically, they could, but it is misleading to say so when addressing a practical problem.) And the problem should first be understood before considering the fixes (which may or may not help, and may or may not cause unexpected side effects if used indiscriminately.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should check using the IE developer tools console to see what the CSS is. As I am not on a Windows machine at the moment, I can't tell you offhand how to do it, but maybe someone else could fill this in before I get round to updating it.

My first thought would be that there is a internal browser stylesheet issue somewhere...

Comment: F12 brings up the dev tools in IE